# Can't run some commands after recovering from file system failure on fedora

Tags: linux, fedora

My laptop had sudden power off due to overheating after that i had some problems with file system failure, it was fixed by booting from fedora live cd and running fsck.
 after that i was able to boot my system successfully it's working 
almost probably except i can't run alot of commands like  fsck - ifconfig -smartctl - shutdown - reboot - ip 
the result is always like that :

```
[root@lap-tita mtita]# fsck
bash: fsck: command not found...
Install package 'util-linux' to provide command 'fsck'? [N/y] y


  * Waiting in queue... Failed to install packages: util-linux-2.28.2-
  2.fc25.x86_64 is already installed
 [root@lap-tita mtita]# smartctl
 bash: smartctl: command not found...
 Install package 'smartmontools' to provide command 'smartctl'? [N/y] y


 * Waiting in queue... Failed to install packages: smartmontools-1:6.5-
 1.fc25.x86_64 is already installed

[root@lap-tita mtita]# shutdown
bash: shutdown: command not found...
Install package 'systemd' to provide command 'shutdown'? [N/y] y


* Waiting in queue... Failed to install packages: systemd-231-
14.fc25.x86_64 is already installed

[root@lap-tita mtita]# reboot
bash: reboot: command not found...
Similar command is: 'reboot'
[root@lap-tita mtita]# ifconfig
bash: ifconfig: command not found...
Install package 'net-tools' to provide command 'ifconfig'? [N/y] y


* Waiting in queue... Failed to install packages: net-tools-2.0-
0.40.20160329git.fc25.x86_64 is already installed

[root@lap-tita mtita]#
```

i don't know yer if there are other commands which wouldn't run anymore but now i have no idea what could cause that specially that i'm sure the hard drive is not corrupted and now the file system is clean

Comment: Your filesystem has likely experienced corruption. Just reinstall from known-good media and then restore from backup.

Comment: is there any other we i can fix this ?? because a full clean install would require a lot of time to redo all my configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't find the executables to those commands. I think there's three possibilities as to what is going on here:

#### executables corrupted

The files for those executables were corrupted and are now missing. If that's the case you'll want to backup what data you can that is not corrupt and re-install the server. Then restore the data onto the new install.

#### unmounted /lib partition

If you have a separate partition for /lib that is not mounted that could result in this type of behavior since the executables would not be accessible while that partition was unmounted. To fix that you'd simply have to mount it. You'd have to have some personal knowledge of the server for this one to know if you had a separate partition for it and which one it was to mount it.

#### PATH env variable wrong

Lastly, if the user you were using had a PATH environment variable that was not set to look in the correct places for the executables you could get this problem. You could run `echo $PATH` or `env | grep -E "^PATH="` to see what  it was set to. An example of a root user's PATH would be:

```
/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/root/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11
```